# Pagination, session and a controller's action - Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a list of friends which should be displayed 3 in a page. Each friend has a category and I also have a drop down menu to choose to view only the friends which are from the chosen category. They should also be display 3 in a page. The way in which filtered and not filtered friends are displayed is the same so I didn't want to have two almost actions in my controller and two identic templates, so I tried to make this in one controller's action and template, but there is a problem. I can't make the pagination for the second and following pages of the filtered friends. Pleae help! :( The problem is that I use a form and when I click on the second page, the variable which was filled in the form and binded, become undefined. Here is the code:

1. **Controller's action**

   ```
   public function displayAction($page, Request $request)
   {
       $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
       $user = $this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();

       $cat = new Category();

       $dd_form = $this->createForm(new ChooseCatType($user->getId()), $cat);

       if($request->get('_route')=='filter')
       {
           if($request->getMethod() == 'POST')
           {

               $dd_form->bindRequest($request);

               if($cat->getName() == null)
               {      
                   return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('home_display'));
               }

               $filter = $cat->getName()->getId();
               if ($dd_form->isValid())
               {   
                   $all_friends = $em->getRepository('EMMyFriendsBundle:Friend')
                                     ->filterFriends($filter);
                   $result = count($all_friends);
                   $FR_PER_PAGE = 3;
                   $pages = $result/$FR_PER_PAGE;
                   $friends = $em->getRepository('EMMyFriendsBundle:Friend')
                                 ->getFilteredFriendsFromTo($filter, $FR_PER_PAGE, ($page-1)*$FR_PER_PAGE); 

                   $link = 'filter';
               }
           }
       }

       else
       {
           $all_friends = $user->getFriends();

           $result = count($all_friends);
           $FR_PER_PAGE = 3;
           $pages = $result/$FR_PER_PAGE;

           $friends = $em->getRepository('EMMyFriendsBundle:Friend')
                         ->getFriendsFromTo($user->getId(), $FR_PER_PAGE, ($page-1)*$FR_PER_PAGE); 

           $link = 'home_display';
       }

       // Birthdays
       $birthdays = null;
       $now = new \DateTime();
       $now_day = $now->format('d');
       $now_month = $now->format('m');

       foreach ($all_friends as $fr)
       {
           if($fr->getBirthday() != null)
           {    
               if($fr->getBirthday()->format('d') == $now_day && $fr->getBirthday()->format('m') == $now_month)
               {
                   $birthdays[]=$fr;
                   $fr->setYears();
               }
           }
       }

       // Search
       $search = new Search();
       $s_form = $this->createFormBuilder($search)
           ->add('words', 'text', array(
           'label' => 'Search: ',
           'error_bubbling' => true))
           ->getForm();


       // Renders the template
       return $this->render('EMMyFriendsBundle:Home:home.html.twig', array(
           'name' => $name, 'friends' => $friends, 'user' => $user, 'birthdays' => $birthdays, 'pages' => $pages, 'page' => $page, 'link' => $link,
           'dd_form' => $dd_form->createView(), 's_form' => $s_form->createView()));
   }
   ```
2. **Template**

   ```
   {% if birthdays != null %}
           <div>

               <img class="birthday" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/1/d/a/6/11970917161615154558carlitos_Balloons.svg.med.png">

               <div class="try"> 
                   This friends have birthday today: 
                   {% for bd in birthdays %}

                       <p>
                           <a href="{{ path('friend_id', {'id': bd.id}) }}">{{ bd.name }}</a>
                           <span class="years">
                               ({{ bd.years }} years)
                           </span>
                       </p>

                   {% endfor %}
               </div>

           </div>
       {% endif %}

       {% for fr in friends %}

           {# TODO: Fix where are shown #}

           {% if fr.getWebPath()!=null %}
               <a href="{{ path('friend_id', {'id': fr.id}) }}">
                   <img class="avatar" src="{{ fr.getWebPath }}">
               </a>
           {% endif %}

           {% if loop.index is odd %}
                   <p class="list1">
               {% else %}
                   <p class="list2">
           {% endif %}
                       <a class="friends" href="{{ path('friend_id', {'id': fr.id}) }}">{{ fr.name }}</a>
                   </p>

       {% endfor %}

       {# TODO: Pagination #}
       {% if pages>1 %}
       <p>
       {% for i in 0..pages %}

               {% if page == loop.index %}
               <span class="pagination">{{ loop.index }}</span>

               {% else %}
               <span class="pagination"><a  href="{{ path(link, {'page': loop.index}) }}">{{ loop.index }}</a></span>
               {% endif %}

       {% endfor %}
       </P>
       {% endif %}

       <p>Choose category:</p>   
       <form class="search" action="{{ path('filter') }}" method="post" {{ form_enctype(s_form) }}> 
           {{ form_widget(dd_form.name) }}
           {{ form_rest(dd_form) }}
           <input type="submit" value="Show friends" />
       </form>
   ```
3. **Repository**

   ```
    class FriendRepository extends EntityRepository
   {
       public function getFriendsFromTo ($user, $limit, $offset)
       {
            return $this->getEntityManager()
               ->createQuery('SELECT f FROM EMMyFriendsBundle:Friend f WHERE f.user='.$user. 'ORDER BY f.name ASC')
               ->setMaxResults($limit)
               ->setFirstResult($offset)
               ->getResult();
       }
   public function filterFriends ($filter)
       {
           $q = $this->createQueryBuilder('f');
   ```

   ```
       $q->select('f')
         ->where('f.category = :filter')            
         ->setParameter('filter', $filter);

       return $q->getQuery()->getResult();
   }

   public function getFilteredFriendsFromTo ($filter, $limit, $offset)
   {
       $q = $this->createQueryBuilder('f');

       $q->select('f')
         ->where('f.category = :filter')
               ->setMaxResults($limit)
           ->setFirstResult($offset)
         ->setParameter('filter', $filter);

       return $q->getQuery()->getResult();
   }
   }
   ```

I tried a lot of things, but there is always a problem. In this code it says that the variable `$all_friends` in the birthday for loop is not defined - and yes, it isn't. Maybe I have to store it in session and I tried this:

```
    $session = $this->getRequest()->getSession();

    $session->set('all_friends');
```

and then passing `$friends=$session->get('all_friends');` to the for loop, but it doesn't work and isn't the variable `$all_friends` too big to store it?

Any ideas will be apreciated! Thank you for your time and effort!

---

**EDIT**

When I use the way with the session and

```
    $session = $this->getRequest()->getSession();

    $session->set('all_friends');

    $fri=$session->get('all_friends');

    foreach ($fri as $fr)
    { .... }
```

the error I get is

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\MyFriends\src\EM\MyFriendsBundle\Controller\HomeController.php line 100
```

and also

```
Warning: Missing argument 2 for Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session::set(), called in C:\xampp\htdocs\MyFriends\src\EM\MyFriendsBundle\Controller\HomeController.php on line 71 and defined in C:\xampp\htdocs\MyFriends\app\cache\dev\classes.php line 148
```

When I don't use session I get

`Notice: Undefined variable: all_friends in C:\xampp\htdocs\MyFriends\src\EM\MyFriendsBundle\Controller\HomeController.php line 100`

when I choose a category to show the friends from it, and I click its second page.

P.S. The lines from the errors don't corespond to the lines in the code I pasted, bacause I skipped some parts of the action, repository and template, because they don't have a part in this problem and they work correctly. If someone wishes, I can send him or update here all the code.

Comment: Can you please put the exect error message ?

Comment: can you post the error message so i can check where it occurs

Comment: the line 100 is in your if condition where you get $all_friends or in else ?

Comment: The line 100 is foreach ($all_friends as $fr) It's some lines below //Birthdays

Comment: just above the foreach loop write this var_dump($all_friends); and check what is coming in $all_friends

Comment: It doesn't show anything, just the error, but I think that it's undefined, because it is in if statement, connected with a form and POST and so on, and when I hit the button to get to the second page, all the information about what was written in the form is lost, and the method is no longer POST.

Comment: The best way in symfony2 is to use annotaions for your actions and dont check for 'POST'. when you click on the button you are not redirecting anywhere but just rendering home tempalte. Just write $all_friends = $em->getRepository('EMMyFriendsBundle:Friend')
                                  ->filterFriends($filter);
before the foreach loop and let see what it says

Comment: It says that $filter is not defined...

Comment: also write $filter = $cat->getName()->getId();
before the query

Comment: Is it still giving the error ?

Comment: Do you really use `$session->set('all_friends')` without second argument?

Comment: mmm yes :S I don't know what to write there, it's the value, isn't it? But in my case the value is the result of a query and it can contain a lot of information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting nothing on session :

```
$session->set('all_friends');
```

You should be doing this instead:

```
$session->set('all_friends', $data);
```

You should really start respecting Symfony2 coding standards too.

My eyes are melting when I try to read your code. You should read [this](http://symfony.com/doc/master/contributing/code/standards.html) and don't forget to create form class instead of creating form in your controller.

**EDIT:** If your $data is a result from a Doctrine2 query, I suggest that you store only the `entity id` and the `entity class` in order to fetch them later when you need it.

**EDIT2:** Here's some code that might help you saving on session filters data. PS, don't forget to add the missing `use ....`

```
/**
 * Set filters
 *
 * @param array  $filters Filters
 * @param string $type    Type
 */
public function setFilters($name, array $filters = array())
{
    foreach ($filters as $key => $value) {
        // Transform entities objects into a pair of class/id
        if (is_object($value)) {
            if ($value instanceof ArrayCollection) {
                if (count($value)) {
                    $filters[$key] = array(
                        'class' => get_class($value->first()),
                        'ids' => array()
                    );
                    foreach ($value as $v) {
                        $identifier = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getUnitOfWork()->getEntityIdentifier($v);
                        $filters[$key]['ids'][] = $identifier['id'];
                    }
                } else {
                    unset($filters[$key]);
                }
            } elseif (!$value instanceof \DateTime) {
                $filters[$key] = array(
                    'class' => get_class($value),
                    'id'    => $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getUnitOfWork()->getEntityIdentifier($value)
                );
            }
        }
    }

    $this->getRequest()->getSession()->set(
        $name,
        $filters
    );
}

/**
 * Get Filters
 *
 * @param array $filters Filters
 * @param type  $type    Type
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function getFilters($name, array $filters = array())
{
    $filters = array_merge(
        $this->getRequest()->getSession()->get(
            $name,
            array()
        ),
        $filters
    );

    foreach ($filters as $key => $value) {
        // Get entities from pair of class/id
        if (is_array($value) && isset($value['class'])) {
            if (isset($value['id'])) {
                $filters[$key] = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->find($value['class'], $value['id']);
            } elseif (isset($value['ids'])) {
                $data = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository($value['class'])->findBy(array('id' => $value['ids']));
                $filters[$key] = new ArrayCollection($data);
            }
        }
    }

    return $filters;
}
```

**EDIT3:** Why you're not using [KnpPaginatorBundle](https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpPaginatorBundle) for pagination ?

Comment: It's a bit old question and even I don't know why the form is in the controller. As for the coding standards :( except from the form in the controller is there something totally wrong with the way the code is written and its logic, or just 'cosmetic' things like the patanthesis of if/else, and the variable's names with underscores? I know that they are very important, too, I will fix them. Thank you for mentioning it :) I really want to learn to write good and readable code.